# Star and Delta Connections using Circuitikz

Tags: graphics, circuitikz, circuits

I am making the delta and star connections in circuitikz. But I have some problems stylizing ...

For the Star Connection:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} \draw

(2.5,1.5) node[circ, scale=0.6] (circ-a1) {a}
(0,1) node[circ, scale=0.6] (circ-a2) {a}
(2.5,1) node[circ, scale=0.6] (circ-b1) {b}
(1.5,1) node[circ, scale=0.6] (circ-b2) {b}
(2.5,0) node[circ, scale=0.6] (circ-c1) {c}
(0.75,0) node[circ, scale=0.6] (circ-c2) {c}
(2.5,0.5) node[circ, scale=0.6] (circ-n1) {N}
(0.75,0.5) node[circ, scale=0.6] (circ-n2) {N}
(circ-c2) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.7cm, sV, scale=0.5] (circ-n2)
(circ-n2) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.7cm, sV, scale=0.5] (circ-b2)
(circ-n2) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.7cm, sV, scale=0.5] (circ-a2)
(circ-b1) -- (circ-b2)
(circ-c1) -- (circ-c2)
(circ-n1) -- (circ-n2)
(circ-a1) -- ++ (-2.5,0) -- (circ-a2)

;\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And for the Delta:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} \draw

(2.5,1.5) node[circ, scale=0.6] (circ-a1) {a}
(1,1.5) node[circ, scale=0.6] (circ-a2) {a}
(2.5,0.5) node[circ, scale=0.6] (circ-b1) {b}
(2,0.5) node[circ, scale=0.6] (circ-b2) {b}
(2.5,0) node[circ, scale=0.6] (circ-c1) {c}
(0,0.5) node[circ, scale=0.6] (circ-c2) {c}
(circ-b2) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.7cm, sV, scale=0.5] (circ-a2)
(circ-c2) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.7cm, sV, scale=0.5] (circ-a2)
(circ-c2) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.7cm, sV, scale=0.5] (circ-b2)
(circ-a1) -- (circ-a2)
(circ-b1) -- (circ-b2)
(circ-c1) -- ++ (-2.5,0) -- (circ-c2)
;\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like the Indices to be observable without changing the size of the nodes. And there are some lines I would like to remove. Also I want to know if there is a way to place the polarity in the voltage sources. Something similar to these images:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution with `circuitikz`, which I really find easier than plain `tikz` (but that's a matter of personal preferences, and being one of the maintainers of `circuitikz`, I am biased).

I write circuits (with relative and interdependent coordinates) to make them easily adjustable and reusable. Comments in the code will explain it.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[
    american]
    \path (0,0) coordinate(n) node[above,red]{$n$};
    % We want a star; let's use polar coordinates
    \draw(n) to[sV, v =$V_{cn}$, *-o] ++(-90:3) coordinate(c) node[left,red]{$c$};
    \draw(n) to[sV, v<=$V_{bn}$, *-o] ++(30:3)  coordinate(b) node[above,red]{$b$};
    \draw(n) to[sV, v<=$V_{an}$, *-o] ++(150:3) coordinate(a) node[left,red]{$a$};
    % leads; the first one determines the horizontal shift (coordinate hh)
    % just change the ++(5,0) here and all will move logically
    \draw (c) to[short, o-o] ++(5,0) coordinate(hh) node[red,right]{$C$};
    % now we use the syntax -| ( horizontal -| vertical) to draw the wires
    \draw (b) to[short, o-o] (b -| hh) node[red,right]{$B$};
    \draw (n) to[short, o-o] (n -| hh) node[red,right]{$N$};
    % a is a bit more complex because it's not straight on
    \draw (a) to[short, o-] ++(0,1) coordinate(aa) % small vertical wire
          to[short,-o] (aa -| hh) node[red,right]{$A$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: beautiful star connected generatos :-)]

Important notes about the circuit:

1. you have to adjust the voltage directions by hand, but it's not difficult. There is a bit of [long-term discussion about it](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/101) on the main site;
2. try not to superimpose wires with no connections (`[short]`) with open connections (`[short, o-]`); it can be ugly (we could fill the circles, but I do not like that solution either);
3. triangle-connection is left as an exercise for the <del>student</del>reader.

And about the circuit (*electronics professor hat on*): obviously, the voltages are sinusoidal, but they **do** have polarity: when having, for example, two sources, it says *when and if* they are both positive - it conveys the all-important concept of relative phase. If you switch one generator in a system, you change the sign of power — from dissipating to generating. So signs **are** relevant.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

with `tikz` is simpler than with `circuitikz`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{
 sV/.style = {circle, draw, fill=white,
              minimum size=6mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
              node contents={\Large$\sim$}},
dot/.style = {circle,fill, minimum size=2mm,
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
              node contents={}},
cir/.style = {circle,draw, fill=white, minimum size=2mm,
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
              node contents={}}
        }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw   (0,0) node (n) [dot,label={[text=red]above:n}]
              -- node [sV,label=right:$V_{cn}$] ++ (270:2)   node (c) [cir,label=below:$c$]
        (0,0) -- node [sV,label=above:$V_{bn}$] ++ ( 30:2)   node (b) [cir,label=above:$b$]
        (0,0) -- node [sV,label=above:$V_{an}$] ++ (150:2)   node (a) [cir,label= left:$a$];
\draw[-o]   (a) |- ++ (4.5,1)         node[right,text=red] (a')  {A};
\draw[-o]   (b)  -- (b -| a'.west)  node [right,text=red] {B};
\draw[-o]   (n)  -- (n -| a'.west)  node [right,text=red] {N};
\draw[-o]   (c)  -- (c -| a'.west)  node [right,text=red] {C};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw   (0,0) -- node [sV] ++ (2,0)     node (b) [dot,label=below:b]
              -- node [sV] ++ (120:2)   node (c) [dot,label=above:c]
              -- node [sV] ++ (240:2)   node (a) [dot,label=below left:a];
\draw[-o]   (a) |- ++ (3,-1)   node[right] (a')  {a};
\draw[-o]   (b)  -- (b -| a'.west)  node [right] {b};
\draw[-o]   (c)  -- (c -| a'.west)  node [right] {c};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

note: alternate voltage source hasn't polarity (as far as i know), consequently i omit signs `+` and `-`.

Comment: I agree with you. As far as I know, alternate voltage source doesn't have polarity. But I took those last images from a book called engineering circuit analysis. Why do they have polarity in the images?

Comment: And also ... I liked the output using tikz ... But if it is simpler. What's the point of using circuitikz?

Comment: @Delfin, `circuitikz` is very useful for drawing more demanding *electronic* scheme, for example see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395535/  :-) it works fine if elements are horizontally or vertically aligned (as show my experiences). and manuals: you should always use some logic in reading it ... they can contain errors

Answer (score 0):

I extended Rmano's solution by replacing the internal dots with filled-in dots using \tikzset to create a dot style, and I added a Delta source, since this also arises quite often.  I also used an embedded scope for the Delta source, shifting the coordinates down by 7 cm.  This makes it feasible to use zero-based coordinates for both drawings without having the two diagrams overlap.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\tikzset{dot/.style={fill,circle,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[
  american]
  % Draw a Wye source
  \path (0,0) coordinate(n) node[above,red]{$n$};
  % we want a star, let's use polar coordinates
  \draw(n) to[sV, v<=$V_{cn}$, *-o] ++(-90:3) coordinate(c) node[left,red]{$c$};
  \draw(n) to[sV, v<=$V_{bn}$, *-o] ++(30:3)  coordinate(b) node[above,red]{$b$};
  \draw(n) to[sV, v<=$V_{an}$, *-o] ++(150:3) coordinate(a) node[left,red]{$a$};
  % leads; the first one determines the horizontal shift (coordinate hh)
  % just change the ++(5,0) here and all will move logically
  \draw (c) to[short, o-o] ++(5,0) coordinate(hh) node[red,right]{$C$};
  % now we use the syntax -| ( horizontal -| vertical) to draw the wires
  \draw (b) to[short, o-o] (b -| hh) node[red,right]{$B$};
  \draw (n) to[short, o-o] (n -| hh) node[red,right]{$N$};
  % a is a bit more complex, because it's not straight on
  \draw (a) to[short, o-] ++(0,1) coordinate(aa) % small vertical wire
  to[short,-o] (aa -| hh) node[red,right]{$A$};
  \draw (a) node[dot] {};
  \draw (b) node[dot] {};
  \draw (c) node[dot] {};
  \draw (n) node[dot] {};
  % Draw a delta source
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-7cm]
    \path (0,0) coordinate(n) ;
    \draw (n) ++( -30:2) coordinate(a) node[below,red]{$a$};
    \draw (n) ++(  90:2) coordinate(c) node[above,red]{$c$};
    \draw (n) ++(-150:2) coordinate(b) node[left,red]{$b$};
    \draw (c) to[sV, v =$V_{ca}$, o-o] (a);
    \draw (a) to[sV, v =$V_{ab}$, o-o] (b);
    \draw (b) to[sV, v =$V_{bc}$, o-o] (c);
    \draw (c) to[short, o-o] (c-|hh) node[red,right]{$C$};
    \draw (a) to[short, o-o] (a-|hh) node[red,right]{$A$};
    \draw (b) to[short,o-] ++(0,-1.5) coordinate(bb) % small vertical wire
    (bb) to[short,-o] (bb -| hh) node[red,right] {$B$};
    \draw (a) node[dot] {};
    \draw (b) node[dot] {};
    \draw (c) node[dot] {};
  \end{scope}
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]