# Improving my circuit : jump crossing, block layout

Tags: circuitikz, alignment

I drew a circuit that works, but there are a few small errors that I can't fix:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[european, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[en amp](aop1){AO1};
\draw (aop1.+) 
    to[short] ++(0,-2) node[ground](GND){};
\draw (aop1.-) 
    --++(0,1.5) coordinate (in-1) 
    --++(-2,0)  node[npn, photo, anchor=E](photo){} ;
\draw (photo.C) 
    --++(-2,0) coordinate (pile) 
    to[battery2] (pile|-GND);
\draw (in-1) 
    to [vR, mirror] (in-1 -|aop1.out) 
    to[short] (aop1.out);
\draw (aop1.out)  
    --++(1,0) coordinate (out1) 
    to[R] ++(2,0) coordinate (in-2)  
    --++(0.5,0) node[en amp, anchor=-](aop2){AO2};
\draw (photo.C) 
    --(photo.C-|out1) coordinate (jump);
\node at (aop1.out-|jump) [jump crossing, rotate=90](J){};
\draw (jump)
    -- (J.east);
\draw (J.west)
    to[pR, n=curseur] (jump|-GND)
    to [short] (jump|-GND) ;
\draw (in-2) 
    --(in-2|-curseur.wiper) coordinate(ao2r) 
    to[R] (ao2r-|curseur.wiper) 
    to[short] (curseur.wiper);
\draw (aop2.+)
    to[short] (aop2.+|-GND);
\draw (in-2)
    --++(0,1.5) coordinate(RC)
    to [R] (RC -|aop2.out);
\draw (RC)
    --++(0,1) coordinate (C) 
    to[C] (C-|aop2.out)
    to[short] (aop2.out);
\path (aop2.center) ++(2,0) coordinate (in-3) ++(1,0) node[en amp, anchor=-](aop3){};
\draw (aop2.out)
    -| (aop3.-);
\draw (jump)
    --(jump-|in-3) coordinate (jump2);
\node at (aop2.out-|jump2) [jump crossing, rotate=90](J2){};
\draw (jump2)
    -- (J2.east);
\draw (J2.west)
    to[pR, n=curseur2] (jump2|-GND)
    to [short] (jump2|-GND) ;
\draw (aop3.+)
    -|(curseur2.wiper);
\draw (aop3.out) 
    to[R] ++(3,0) coordinate (ledR)
    to[leDo] (ledR|-GND);
\draw (GND)
    to[short] (GND-|ledR);
\draw (GND)
    to[short] (GND-|pile);
\end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```

- jump crossing : I have drawn them vertically using `\node at (aop1.out-|jump) [jump crossing, rotate=90](J){};` but there is still a slight horizontal line: how do I remove it?

[image]

thank you for the time spent helping me improve my code.

Comment: Hmm... this is not exactly a *minimal* example, isn't it? It would be much better if you prepared three different questions, each one with a minimal example of only the problem you have. BTW, I do not understand what the problem with the jump crossing is...

Comment: Ok, I split the question into 3.

Comment: Great! That way they will be more useful for other people, too. About the problem with the jump crossing, please try to add a screenshot to show where the problem is... Thanks!

Comment: @Nicolas for the jump crossing have alook at the answer here if it looks better -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581818/197451

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522213/wire-crossings-problem

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134067/circuitikz-wire-kink-thingy-when-wires-cross

Comment: Regarding the dashed rectangle.  You can use the fit tikzlibrary as in `\node[draw=dashed,fit=(a) (b)](name){};`  I started to modify your MWE, but there are just too many node names for me to dig out of the code.  Place text [below] at (name.south).

Comment: @JohnKormylo : thanks, this answer helped me a lot to find the information I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Update for anyone still looking to solve this problem: `circuitikz` crossings can be used as a node or path. In the node style, `[jump crossing]` produces the aforementioned horizontal line. In path style, `[xing]` does *not* produce the horizontal line. See page section 4.10 of the circuiTikZ 1.6.6 documentation, page 45

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[european, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0) to [xing] (1,0)
(1,0) to node[jump crossing]{} (2,0)
\end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Path vs node styles of jump crossing in circuiTikZ 1.6.6]